# nth-of-type; how to target multiple divs within one ( )

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make every fourth `div` have a `margin-left:0`; however, currently I am making a separate entry for each `div` as follows:

```
   .product_display:nth-of-type(1)  {
    margin-left: 0;
}
   .product_display:nth-of-type(5)  {
    margin-left: 0;
}
   .product_display:nth-of-type(9)  {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
   .product_display:nth-of-type(1,5,9)  {
 margin-left: 0;
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.product_display:nth-child(4n+1)  {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

- 4 * 0 + 1 = 1st div
- 4 * 1 + 1 = 5th div
- 4 * 2 + 1 = 9th div
  etc...

Comment: I tried applying it but i cant seem to get it to work, Which one would I use to target every 4th div?

Comment: Do you mean `nth-of-child`?

Comment: @user2055697 use `nth-of-child` instead of `nth-of-type` and do the same as mentioned above..

Comment: It's `nth-child` not `nth-of-child`.